# Getting CORS error instead of Error 500 (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present)

Tags: angular, cors, backend, fastapi

Yesterday I asked a question about CORS error that I was getting when trying to do a POST request to FastApi backend from Angular app. After a few comments I decided to delete the question to re-check everything better.

So things are a bit weird. In my FastApi backend I have the following functions:

```py
@app.post("/hello")
def read_root(request: Request):
    print(request)
    client_host = request.client.host
    return {"client_host": client_host}

@app.post("/pattern-data")
def pattern_input(payload: PatternReconData) -> Dict:
    # Does stuff and falls over tragically
    return result   # this doesn't happen of course
```

and in my front-end I'm trying both of these:

```js
    this.apiService.sendRequest('hello', 'howdy').subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('done');
      }
    );
    this.apiService.sendRequest('pattern-data', payload).subscribe(
      (response: SuccessResponse) => {
        console.log(response);
        /* do stuff */
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('done');
      },
    );
```

What's strange is that if I test sending some values to `'pattern-data'` in Swagger UI it comes back with Error 500 since the script falls over. The `'hello'` works just fine.

[image: Swagger UI response]

Similarly, going from the front-end app if I poke the `.../hello` I get the expected response:

```
{client_host: '<some valid ip>'}
```

but when trying to send values to `.../pattern-data` results in CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://<my-backend-server>/pattern-data' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Yet I know that the backend had successfully received the payload because if I look at backend logs I see this.:

```
2021-09-16 02:42:38.0130,main,DEBUG,Pattern name received from front-end {data}
```

So this suggests that the pre-flight check was successful and web app was allowed to communicate with the backend so it all has nothing to do with CORS.

This is a bit confusing and caused me quite a lot of grief having spent  time researching CORS and how to deal with CORS errors, while in reality my issue has nothing to do with it.

I don't understand why I'm not getting an Error 500 but a CORS error instead. Is this because the back-end simply fails to send a response and browser (Chrome) interprets no response as not having necessary headers and shows CORS error?

This is from Chrome dev tools Headers section. Poking `/hello`:

```
Request URL: http://<my-backend-server>/hello
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: <some valid ip>
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:4200
content-length: 31
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 16 Sep 2021 02:43:09 GMT
server: uvicorn
vary: Origin
```

sending data to `/pattern-data`:

```
Request URL: http://<my-backend-server>/pattern-data
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-length: 21
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 16 Sep 2021 02:43:09 GMT
server: uvicorn
```

Comment: Well, the error says it all, the cors headers are missing in the response from the service. In the swagger UI it's probably working because this is served by swagger themselves (thus there is no cross origin). When you are requesting from your localhost, the server does not send any cors headers, thus your browser rejects to access the data in the response.

Comment: @derpirscher fair enough but as I understood it, CORS is meant to be a pre-flight check that's conducted *before* front-end is allowed to communicate with the back-end. But what I have is that backend is successfully receiving the data, which to me means that there was a handshake and the POST method was allowed to go through.

Comment: CORS does not guide anything about a POST method going through - it's only relevant to whether the client is allowed to read the response (i.e. the request still happens as long as the the OPTIONS call (preflight) is OK-ed - this happens without running the view code where the 500 error occurs).

Comment: @MatsLindh, sorry my understanding might be a bit off. But then I need to specify in FastApi CORS middleware that for example POST and GET methods are allowed. So CORS should be allowing or rejecting the method coming through. Otherwise it would be a pointless security feature if malicious code can be sent anyway and only thing monitored is the ability to get response.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the goal of CORS is - it will verify that the `Origin` header that a browser sends is among the accepted origins, and it will tell the requesting browser that it is allowed to read the response from the service. If you make an explicit HTTP request, it'll pass regardless of any CORS restrictions (for example using `curl` or similar). It protects you from 3rd party sites making requests to a resource on behalf of the browser of the user (the `Origin:` would be different than what you expected).

Comment: @MatsLindh, this is what I see on Wiki page: "...the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method." So in my case this means that preflight succeeded, then front-end sent the data but when backend failed a CORS error was reported by the browser. Just seems weird.

Comment: When the error happens, the expected CORS headers on the _response_ is not present (since an exception happened, the middleware does not run). Since the expected CORS headers are not present, the browser returns a CORS error, even if the underlying error is a 500 error - since the request doesn't have the required CORS headers, the browser can't reporting anything else than a CORS error (since it would otherwise leak information that it hasn't been allowed to provide).

Comment: @MatsLindh, ok cool. I get it now. Would you mind submitting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the error happens, the expected CORS headers on the response are *not* present (since an exception happened, the middleware does not run).

As the expected CORS headers are missing, the browser doesn't have any other option than returning a CORS error, even if the underlying error is a 500 error. If it did return more information, then the browser would leak information that it wasn't allowed to read (since there is no CORS header present).

CORS only protect you against compliant clients (i.e. proper browsers) not letting third party sites make requests on behalf of the browser's user; it does not stop any other person from making a random request against your service with curl or something similar (but they wouldn't have access to the information that would make it possible to make the request in the context of the browser's user).